# Pymongo find() stalls

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

**Issue**: have a large collection of transactions that I want to read from MongoDb for a given day. No matter how I try to read a days worth, my read always stalls. The stall point is always the same but can be changed based on my batch size setting.

**System**: Linux-Mint, Python: 3.5, MongoDB 3.2, PyMongo

**Code:**

```
def write_transactions_to_file(start: datetime, end: datetime, filename: str):
    print ("Writing transactions to file")
    new_start = start
    new_end = new_start + timedelta(hours=1)

    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        while new_start < end:
            print("Starting hour {}".format(new_start.hour))
            query = Builder().find(TimeStamp=Gt(new_start)).And(TimeStamp=Lt(new_end)).query
            transactions = find(tx_collection, query)

            for c, t in enumerate(transactions):
                j = json.dumps(t, default=json_util.default)
                f.write("{}\n".format(j))
                print("{}:{}".format(c,t))

            new_start=new_start+timedelta(hours=1)
            new_end = new_start+timedelta(hours=1)

    print("Transactions written to file")

def find(self, collection, query):
    return collection.find(query).batch_size(25)
```

value of "query" = {'$and': [{'TimeStamp': {'$gt': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 24, 0, 0)}}, {'TimeStamp': {'$lt': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 24, 1, 0)}}]}

**Tried**:
Originally, I  just queried for the entire day. That got me around 16k records before stalling. I later changed the batch size to 100, which got me up to ~29k records before stalling. Next I tried limiting the query to one hour at a time. That too, always stalls (same place each time). However, the point at which it stalls is different based on the batch size.

Comment: Do you have an index on the `Timestamp` field?

Comment: It is part of a compound index - but not a stand alone.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that could be the issue:

1. If the index on the `Timestamp` field is not the prefix (see [Compound Indexes: Prefix](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes)) then it's possible that the query was not executed efficiently. Since the query depends heavily on the `Timestamp` field, it's advisable to create either a separate index based on that field, or ensure that the field appear first in any compound index.
2. It is possible that the stalls you're observing is due to the server's memory filling up and thus it's trying to get more documents from disk. This waiting for disk access could be the stalls. You can determine if this is the case by using `iostat` and see if the stall periods correspond to high disk utilization. This is usually an issue if your server is using a spinning disk instead of SSD.